# Почему SQL Server рекомендует именно такой индекс?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Есть битовое поле и есть числовое поле, которое может иметь 5 значений.

Так вот, SQL Server советует сделать индекс следующего вида: Bit,Int для такого условия:

```
BitField= 1 and (IntField in (1,2,3) or IntField is null)
```

Почему именно в этом порядке, ведь кол-во уникальных значений в INT выше?

Если пойти наперекор ему и на первое место поставить int, то будет выполняться сканирование индекса, а если сделать так, как он хочет, то будет поиск, который будет вложенными циклами объединяться через интервал слияния.

Оба запрос выполняются ~ одинаковое время.

Вроде, везде пишут, что нужно поля в индексе ставить от наиболее уникального к менее уникальному.

Ну и вот наполняемость таблицы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну и еще какую-то странность обнаружил при экспериментах:

Если слить данные во `#временную таблицу`, то он просит только индекс на интовое поле, но запрос выполняется моментально.

Если слить в новую постоянную таблицу, то просит снова индексы на 2-ух полях, но запрос снова выполняется моментально без индексов.

Вот если делать такую же выборку `COUNT(*)` с такими же фильтрами из основной таблицы, то запрос висит секунд 20, хотя `WITH(NOLOCK)` стоит => тормоза из-за блокировок исключены.

Очень странно, хотя планы визуально идентичные. Может влиять на скорость то, что в исходной таблице есть XML колонка с объемные XML, хоть я их и не вывожу в запросе?

Comment: Если предположить, что записей с BitField=1 примерно половина то максимум потребуется сканирование половины индекса, если это поле первое. А если оно второе - то скорее всего потребуется полное сканирование индекса. Но дьявол как всегда в деталях, в количестве тех или иных значений в БД

Comment: @Mike добавил наполняемость. Мне казалось, что он не собирает статистику, если на полях нету индекса.

Comment: а дело не в статистике которую собирает БД. Пройтись по части индекса с 2.7 млн записей несколько проще, чем по всему индексу с 7 млн.А операции OR и IN вообще плохо по индексам работают. ему же фактически надо будет несколько независимых поисков делать начиная с разных точек. И при такой статистике вполне вероятно что отсутствие индекса будет ничем не хуже (а может и лучше). Селективность то итоговая все равно очень низкая (но это уже зависит от того какие поля вообще запросом вытаскиваются, нужно ли ему на основе индекса потом в данные лезть)

Comment: Изменится ли предложение, если IntField сделать Not Null? проверьте...

Comment: @Mike Тоже так думал, но без индекса вообще печаль... 20 сек выполняется, а с индексом моментально, что и стало для меня открытием...

Comment: @Akina хрень какая-то. Если слить во #временную таблицу данные, то говорит, что ему нужен только индекс на инте и запрос выполняется моментально и без индексов. Если слить в новую отдельную физическую таблицу, то там снова хочет иметь индекс на 2-ух полях, но запрос опять же выполняется моментально. То что в таблице есть рыхлые XML, которые я не вывожу, а в копиях находятся только нужные данные может играть роль? Результатом запросов является COUNT(*).

Comment: Рекомендация ставить более селективный столбец вперёд она для достаточно общего случая, т.е. когда по ключу будут джойны, группировки, и т.п. без скалярных предикатов по части ключа. Когда выборка по полному ключу со скалярным предикатом, то вроде бы вообще всё равно в каком порядке столбцы. Может он их по алфавиту предлагает, или по *column_id* из _sys.columns_. Индекс же под конкретный запрос предлагается.

Comment: @i-one Ну это не отменяет какой-то странности, которую я описал в комментарии чуть выше. В плане разной скорости выполнения запроса...

Comment: так count() в данные не лезет, когда индекс есть. А индекс гораздо меньше по объему в сравнении с таблицей. И вполне возможно, что в таблица физически разрослась за время эксплуатации и там куча свободного места, которое хоть и не используется, но все равно его приходится просматривать при полном скане таблицы. И оптимизатор вполне этот факт способен учитывать

Comment: @Mike, а разве сжатие БД не убирает пустоты?

Comment: должно ... значит не пустоты виноваты, если не помогает. Но если длина записи сильно больше длины записи в индексе то скорость конечно то же будет разная. но это не объясняет факта ускорения после переливки в другую таблицу. Но я не знаю особенностей ms sql и что такое "сжатие таблицы", происходит ли при этом полная реорганизация, или может полностью  пустые блоки только исключаются

Comment: _"Сжатие"_ это вы shrink имеете ввиду? На индексах это плохо сказывается обычно, т.к. они при этом сильнее фрагментируются. Хорошо сказывается rebuild, он и фрагментацию снижает и помогает полнее использовать страницы индекса, т.е. индекс становится более компактный и более сплошной - настолько, насколько это возможно.

Comment: Хотя, нет, всё он правильно предлагает. Всё равно в каком порядке, это когда поиск при полном совпадении ключа (`[KeyField]=@keyValue` либо `[KeyField] is null` и всё это через `and` по всем ключевым столбцам). Здесь же действительно полное совпадение только части ключа, а по другой части ключа альтернативы, поэтому логично вынести bitField как лидирующий столбец, чтобы потом делать range scan по оставшимся условиям. Ну в общем то Mike это написал уже в комментарии выше.